# CircleCI filter branch by prefix

Tags: continuous-integration, circleci, cicd, circleci-workflows

I am making a CICD pipeline with [circle-ci-terraform](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/circle-ci)

My dev branch names are `dev/feature_name` etc. **Instead of running workflows by directly writing the branch name I want to use the prefix `dev/`** so that the same workflow runs for all branches starting with `dev`. Any idea how I can achieve that?

Here's my current workflow -

```
workflows:
  dev_workflow:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                  - dev/cicd-integration
```

I already tried `dev/*`, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CircleCI uses the Java variant of RegEx pattern matching (https://circleci.com/docs/workflows/#using-regular-expressions-to-filter-tags-and-branches).

So in your case, you need to specify the following RegEx pattern:

```
  filters:
    branches:
      only:
        - /^dev\/.*/
```

Comment: doesn't `ignore` tag mean it will ignore dev/feature branch?

Comment: `only` did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Oh indeed! Sorry about that. I guess I was not paying enough attention to what I was typing. Glad you caught that! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Pleasure is mine, and thank you.